# Handling user's input

Tags: c

when I input a floating point number (eg. 48.3) the result displayed is 48.00 instead of 48.30 and whenever I try to input string with empty space the program ends immediately. I need help, how to fix this problem?

```
 int integer;
 char a[50];

 float fnum;
 char b[50];


 printf("Please enter an integer : ");
 scanf("%s",&a);

 integer = atoi(a);

 printf("\nPlease enter a floating-point number : ");
 scanf("%s", &b);

 fnum = atoi(b);

 printf("Output : \n");

 printf("%i + %.2f = %.2f \n", integer,fnum,(integer+fnum));
 printf("%i - %.2f = %.2f \n", integer,fnum,(integer-fnum));
 printf("%i * %.2f = %.2f \n", integer,fnum,(integer*fnum));
```

Comment: Enter an integer: `scanf("%s",&a);` Yeah. No....

Comment: You need to start with a good C tutorial. The `%s` format specifier for `scanf` expects matching *character pointer* and is used to read *strings*. The `%d` format specifier is used for integers. Take time to read through `man scanf` (you can spend hours actually digesting the information) `integer = atoi(a);` looks pretty meaningless unless you have previously declared `int integer;` somewhere. See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where are `a` and `b` declared? What types are they?

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson yes, char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're converting string `b` into an *integer* by calling `atoi`. You want to convert it to a floating point number, so use `atof`:

```
fnum = atof(b);
```

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that `if (scanf ("%f", &b) == 1)` provides a way to validate that a conversion to floating point has actually taken place (the same is true for `if (scanf ("%d", &a) == 1)` for int), while `atoi` and `atof` provide nothing in terms of validation.

Comment: You can also use `strtod()` to convert string to double, and (with a bit more care needed), you can use `strtol()` and its relatives to convert a string to various types of integer.  All of these provide information to let you know whether the conversion succeeded, though some care is needed in interpreting the results (and, in the case of `strtol()`, saying _some care_ is being polite!).

Answer (score 1):

The atoi returns an int. 
The atof returns a float.

```
int integer;
char a[50];

float fnum;
char b[50];


printf("Please enter an integer : ");
scanf("%s",&a);

integer = atoi(a);

printf("\nPlease enter a floating-point number : ");
scanf("%s", &b);

fnum = atof(b);

printf("Output : \n");

printf("%d + %.2f = %.2f \n", integer,fnum,(integer+fnum));
printf("%d - %.2f = %.2f \n", integer,fnum,(integer-fnum));
printf("%d * %.2f = %.2f \n", integer,fnum,(integer*fnum));
```

---